# Setting stars color on hover in star rating system

Tags: jquery, css

I have pretty tricky problem with my stars rating system. 
First Thing, I'm getting stars from CMS and giving them unique id.

When my page is not rated i have :

```
<div class="rated">
    <a class="star" href="#" onclick="star(1,6226,0,0,1439 ,0)" "="">
        <span>★</span>
    </a>
    <a class="star" href="#" onclick="star(2,6226,0,0,1439 ,0)" "="">
        <span>★</span>
    </a>
    <a class="star" href="#" onclick="star(3,6226,0,0,1439 ,0)" "="">
        <span>★</span>
    </a>
    <a class="star" href="#" onclick="star(4,6226,0,0,1439 ,0)" "="">
        <span>★</span>
    </a>
    <a class="star" href="#" onclick="star(5,6226,0,0,1439 ,0)" "="">
        <span>★</span>
    </a>
</div>
```

(@Admin , Morerator - how to make new lines ??)

When my page is rated i have:

```
<div class="punkty" id="punkty1445">
    <div class="rating">
        <a class="star" href="#" onclick="star(1,6256,6,2,1445 ,3)">
            <span>★</span>
        </a>
        <a class="star" href="#" onclick="star(2,6256,6,2,1445 ,3)">
            <span>★</span>
        </a>
        <a class="star" href="#" onclick="star(3,6256,6,2,1445 ,3)">
            <span>★</span>
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="rated">
        <a class="star" href="#" onclick="star(4,6256,6,2,1445 ,3)" "="">
            <span>★</span>
        </a>
        <a class="star" href="#" onclick="star(5,6256,6,2,1445 ,3)" "="">
            <span>★</span>
        </a>
    </div>
    <span class="oc" itemprop="average" id="glos1445" style="font-weight:bold;margin-right: 10px;">3</span>
</div>
```

As you can see in second example  average page rate is set by class rating (i make them green colour). With class rated I'm setting start to be voted (here 3 green 2 blue).
In first example 5 blue so all of them are clickable and when you are only one who vote for 5 we will see 5 green stars after that , I hope you can understand it.

Now my question 
How to make them change colour to gold from left to right when i point to star? 
For exaple , i pointed third star so 1st 2nd and third have to change colour to gold. 
I tried to make that in css but they were gold from right to left ( i cannot show you that because in all jsfiddle etc. It's normal from left to right). I thik that will be possible with some hard-core jquery. Please help me , this is very important to me.

Comment: What is the code for the current star function?

Comment: Can you possibly out the rating as a number into the element called rated? i.e. <div class="rated-<?php echo $num ?>">, where $num is the rounded average of the rating.

Comment: @BarbaraLaird - You mean ajax /jquery function ?

Comment: @ramesh I think it's impossible, somebody before me wrote it and i have to only make it look good . so i need only jquery/css

Comment: @woj_jas Just checked the code you provided. You could simply add the css I gave you. It will work.

Answer (score 1):

If I were you, this is how I will go about this issue. I would use icon fonts for the stars, there free icons fonts available on the web: http://sixrevisions.com/resources/free-icon-fonts/ .

The amazing bit about icon font is that it is easy to implement and you can change the size and the color of the icons the same way you would change the color of font. After implementing icon fonts you can add the following css:

```
.rated{
 color : blue;
} 
.rating{
 color : red;
}
```

By default the stars would be blue and the selection made by the user would turn red.
Tutorial on how to implement icon fonts : http://designshack.net/articles/css/how-to-implement-some-slick-icons-using-a-font-and-css/

If you dont want to do that, you can achieve the same outcome with background images. Created an image sprite of the stars with the two states you need, and change the background position based on the class of the parent container.